# SO dates calculation

Tags: discussion, date-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SO dates calculation and formating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83111/so-dates-calculation-and-formating)

I was wondering what script SO uses for dates displaying, because it seems to be pretty nice formating and logical showing...